# How to refer to a Method that is to be re-implemented in my thesis?

Tags: citations, code

I am writing my thesis (computer sience) and wonder how to refer to an algorithm which i reimplement as a part of the thesis.

There is a paper describing the original algorithm and I am only implementing this algorithm in my thesis.

I considered to refer to it as 'baseline' or 'reference algorithm' but 'baseline do have a different meaning in data mining and in my opinion (as a not native english person 'reference algorithm'
sounds like the algorithm completely differ from mine. The algorithm itself is not named and the paper is having a name that is too long (i.e for the TOC)

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. Can you please [edit] the question to clarify what you already considered and in particular why obvious choices like the name do not work for you?

Answer (score 2):

First, give the algorithm (since it is your thesis, I assume that you have enough space). Then, name the algorithm. If it is named already, better to use that name. Else, caption the algorithm

> Algorithm 5: Managing big data with minimum spanning trees

Then, in the text, you can refer to this algorithm as

> We have implemented Algorithm 5, and we compare the results with our
>   algorithm.

Comment: Also, the reason theorems and algorithms come to have names in the first place is because people write about the algorithms that someone else invented and refer to them as “______’s algorithm.” So feel free to call it ____’s algorithm in your text. Notice that if there are several authors, hyphenating the names or using the authors’ initials is common

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other options:

- "original algorithm" (yours is the "new algorithm")
- "traditional
  algorithm"
- "Smith's algorithm" (Substitute the name of the researcher
  who first published the algorithm for "Smith".)

But "reference algorithm" seems OK to me too.

Comment: Ah ok.. I thought there are special notations for this...